# How to pass object to a class-based view from a function-based view?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to define a Django function-based view that will redirect to another class-based view already defined.

**views.py**

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/details.html'
def albumdelete(request, pk):
    print(pk)
    return DetailView.as_view()(request, pk).get_queryset()
```

**urls.py** (only the relevant part)

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.albumdelete, name='album-delete')
```

Here is the error message I am getting.

```
AttributeError at /music/delete/6/

Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

The actual DetailView is working fine.

Comment: There is a slight chance that some other url is hitting due to a mistake in writing the regex of url,  could you show the complete url config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got to pass pk as a key word argument like this

```
DetailView.as_view()(request, pk=pk).get_queryset()
```